# Accessing Twitter Sample Streaming Endpoint?

Tags: twitter, postman

I'm trying to access the following `GET https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json` end-point in these [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/get/statuses/sample).

From POSTMAN, I set an `Authorization` header with a value of `Basic X` where `X` is equal to the base64 encoding of `$ConsumerKey:$ConsumerSecret`.

When issuing the `GET` call from POSTMAN, I see the following prompt:

[image]

Confused as to why my OAuth credentials aren't accepted, I entered my Twitter user and password.

But, the server replies with:

```
<html>\n
    <head>\n
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n
        <title>Error 401 Unauthorized</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR: 401</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json'. Reason:

            <pre>    Unauthorized</pre>
        </body>
    </html>
```

In addition, I typed in my Consumer Key and Secret for the user and password prompt, but that failed too.

So, how can I hit this endpoint from POSTMAN? I'm not entirely sure if it's a stream. If it is, would I still be able to hit it via POSTMAN?